# SharePoint Versioning issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Good day,
I have hit a speed bump with SharePoint. I have developed a web part and application page, and packaged them in a wsp.

In my dev environment it seems to work with no problems, but when it is deployed in the testing environment it seems to not work. The web part calls the application page on my dev environment, but in the testing environment i get a "file not found screen".

I did some checking on it and found that my dev build version is 14.0.6029.1000 and the testing version is 14.0.7015.1000.

Does this mean my wsp will not work period or will i have to change my code?

Comment: The different versions should not cause a problem however you should probably bring your dev machine up to the same patch level (it needs SP2 installed). Can you post some more information such as the code that calls the application page and a stack trace if it is available (check the ULS logs for this). Also can you verify that the file is indeed deployed to where you expect it to be.

Comment: Im currently using "SPUtility.Redirect(redirectUrl,
                SPRedirectFlags.Static | SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLayoutsPage, HttpContext.Current);" to call the page, all i get is a "file not found"

Comment: Is the file in the correct place under the `Layouts` directory and if so can you enter the URL manually and reach the page?

Comment: Yes its in the layouts directory. Even when giving it the URL manually its giving me the same "file not found" message

Comment: Are you using an `Alternate Access Mapping` url on the test machine?

Comment: I am not using Alternative Access Mapping

Comment: I'm out of ideas, can you edit your question and post your web part code?

Comment: Its good.. Ive found a work around it and its still inline with microsoft standards